# Regular expression to match as less characters as possible

Tags: python, python-re

I want to match `x.py` from `a/b/c/x.py`, when I use `re`:

```py
s = 'a/b/c/x.py'
res = re.search('/(.*.py)?', s).group(1)

>>> res = b/c/x.py
```

This is not what I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to ensure that the element is is the last in a path, you can prepend `(?<=\/)`, a positive lookbehind:

```py
>>> s = 'a/b/c/x.py'
>>> el = re.search(r"(?<=\/)(\w+\.py)", s).group(1)
>>> el
'x.py'
```

Otherwise, if you need to match also `filename.py`, you need to remove it:

```py
>>> s2 = 'file.py'
>>> el = re.search(r"(\w+\.py)", s2).group(1)
>>> el
'file.py'
```

Comment: Thank you @crissal, I'm adopting this answer because I want to use regex and this one is perfect.

Comment: Hi crissal, it will not match `12-x.py`

Comment: ```([\w-]+\.py)```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex, just use `str.rsplit`, with `maxsplit=1`, and take the last item:

```py
>>> s.rsplit('/',1)[-1]
'x.py'
```

Comment: Nice trick, to avoid doing unnecessary splits +1.

Comment: isn't it better to use `os.path.split` or `os.sep` as rsplit param to make is independent for all OS and avoid hassle of handling backslashes? you can see my answer. what say?

Comment: `os.sep` is the better option if that's indeed a path. But OP hasn't mentioned anywhere whether it's really a path, or just some string.

Comment: well, if that's a hardcoded string, then +1 for your solution.

But if he really gets that as a path, then it may fail in aforementioned case. However, +1 given

Answer (score 2):

when you want to extract filename from path, you should use `os.path.split`. The `os.path.split()` method in Python is used to Split the path name into a pair head and tail independent of OS. Here, tail is the last path name component and head is everything leading up to that.

```
import os

path = 'a/b/c/x.py'
res = os.path.split(path)
print(res[1])
```

You can also use `normpath` and `os.sep` for this solution:

```
import os

path = 'a/b/c/x.py'
path = os.path.normpath(path)
res = path.split(os.sep)
print(res[-1])
```

You can use `rsplit` as @ThePyGuy said in this case to avoid more splitting by changing the line to:

```
res = path.rsplit(os.sep,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'a/b/c/x.py'
res = re.search('\w*\.py', s).group() # It will match alphanumeric
# res = re.search(r'[\w&.-]+$', s).group() 
# The above regex will match alphanumeric and the given special characters
```

**EDIT**

To match everything after the last `/` you can use following regex

```
res = re.search('[^/]+$', s).group()
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a splitting approach here:

```py
s = 'a/b/c/x.py'
last = s.split('/')[-1]
print(last)  # x.py
```

Comment: Nice idea to avoid using regex whenever simple method can be used. +1

Comment: isn't it better to use `os.path.split` or `os.sep` as split param in your solution to make it independent for all OS and avoid hassle of handling backslashes? you can see my answer. what say?